# Modification to a RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess

The following RewriteRule works correctly

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

until I place this one just right below

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/$ /profile/company-profile.php?cname=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now every *domain.com/something-here* goes to the *company-profile.php*

How can I fix this ?

Firstly, the *domain.com/login* takes you to the *index.php* of the login folder.
When I type the second RewriteRule, if I write *domain.com/login* again it shows (in the background) the *company-profile.php?cname=login*

Comment: What's the intended effect? Give an example of when the first should occur, and when and why not the second.

Comment: you are redirecting something like: `abc` to /profile/company-profile.php and `abc` to `/$1/` so who ever comes first will rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect company specific request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ profile/company-profile.php?cname=$1 [NC,L]

# redirect all others
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I would like not to have the company part though

Comment: so you want `([a-z0-9\-_]+)` to redirect to profile/company and `(.*)` to everything else?

Comment: I would like if a folder is found to redirect it there, else if not found to the company-profile.php

Comment: so if a folder exists, then you don't really need the second rule `(.*)` since the folder exists, correct? therefore you only need the rule to redirect to the company.

Comment: Nice, thank you for this. I accepted your answer. However, is there a way when I type domain.com/a-company to have always a `/` at the end? It happens on the login folder for example. I a

Comment: yes you will have to redirect the same you did with the `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]`.